# Diff bet time separated by colon (like 23:10:00 minus next day 01:15:00) in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Really appreciate if any one help with below formula in excel,

Diff bet time separated by colon (like 23:10:00 minus next day 01:15:00) in excel

ThanK You.

Comment: The simplest solution is to store the values as date-times.  Date and time are stored in Excel as a single number.  The integer portion is a day count since a reference date and the decimal fraction is time in the form of fraction of a day.  When in this form, you can do any time arithmetic without jumping through hoops adjusting for times crossing midnight.  The readable time displayed as you describe is just formatting.

Comment: @fixer1234 - not sure I agree - if we are talking about work shifts, for example, where the max length will never reach 24 hours, it's relatively simple to deal with shifts that cross midnight by using time values only - see my answer

Comment: @barryhoudini: Darn if you ain't right.  Your solution is simpler.  I stand corrected.  Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have start time in A2 and end time in B2 you can use this formula to get the difference

`=MOD(B2-A2,1)`

format result cell as a time value

That works whether the period crosses midnight or not, e.g. for your example you will get 2:05, for a time period on one day like 15:00 to 22:15 you will still get the correct result, i.e. 7:15

Comment: I had never used MOD with negative numbers and wasn't aware it works that way.  I just learned two things.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of crossing Midnight.  In **A1**:

=TODAY()+TIME(23,10,0)

and in **B1**:

=TODAY()+1+TIME(1,15,0)

and in **C1**:

=B1-A1

and format all three cells as *h:mm:ss*

[image]

Comment: Hi, ThanX for ans. However if need to minus many row in excel how t will work? .For this single entry it;s work fine.

Comment: @NileshChandane - there are many ways to take a formula from one cell and paste it across multiple rows. (drag the handle in the lower left, copy/paste, etc.) Excel will automatically update its cell references, so that the formula in row 2 will reference cells A2 and B2, etc.