# Subtracting time formats in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to calculate the difference between hours. I tried using the formula mentioned above which uses ABS function with TEXT function and IF function, but that didn't work. I also tried activating the '1904 date system' in the "options>advanced>while calculating this workbook" but that didn't work either.

please provide a feasible solution, the values have been given as under:

```
cell d3: 09:36:00 pm (cell format: time)

cell d4: 12:51:00 am (cell format: time)
```

cell f4 contains the formula with custom cell format as `[h]:mm`

Comment: see http://superuser.com/a/940439/364367

Answer (score 0):

If they are **within the same day** then use:

```
=D3-D4
```

and apply the correct formatting:

[image]

This makes sense because **D3** is in the evening and **D4** is very early in the morning.