# Auto Calculate Hours for Shift

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Good Morning,

I am using Excel and have am trying to be able to add a punch in and out time, then have the total time between those automatically be calculated in the next spot.

This works when I do 06:00 and 18:00, but when working nights, it would be backwards. For instance, when using 18:00 to 06:00, I just get an error because they cannot be subtracted from each other. Is there a way around this? I need to use 24 hour time as well. I've attached a quick photo for reference.

Thank you

[Example Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOn7j.png)

Comment: You aren't specific about how the time value is entered (user types the time vs. system time is captured).  Storing the date/time rather than just the time solves this problem (and you can format the displayed value to show just the time).  That's easy to change if you are capturing the system time.  If the time is being manually entered, you can have the entry include the date, or use a workaround, such as entering the time in one place, combining that with the date behind the scenes, and storing the result in another (potentially hidden) location for use in time calculations.

Comment: Good alternate solution: https://superuser.com/a/940439/364367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **1** (24 hours) to the end time, if the end time is smaller than start time. For example;

```
=IF(D4<B4,D4+1-B4,D4-B4)
```

We add 1 because Excel keeps dates and time as numbers and each day is equal to 1, so 24 hours as well.

Comment: Or variation: =D4+(D4<B4)-B4