# Formula to calculate duration for times that can span two days

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Column `A`: Start time in 24-hour format (using the formula `=NOW()` and locked in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>)
Column `B`: End time in 24-hour format (entered the same as for column `A`)
Column `C`: Duration, formatted as `[mm]`, using the formula `=B1-A1`

How do I calculate the duration if the data in column `B` includes times that occur in the following day?

---

Actual worksheet:

[image: Screenshot of actual worksh]

Comment: You need to study date and time formats in excel.  The formula for column C is literally =B1-A1 but for it to work correctly the preceding cells must have valid date/time formats.  It also handles midnight just fine.

Comment: The formula in column C is indeed =b1-a1 and the formatting is in [mm], I forgot to mention that I use the function "CTRL + SHIFT + ;" to lock the time, and the result that I got for now is the duration is negative (-) and did not count the following day.

Comment: See solution https://superuser.com/a/940439/364367

Answer (score 2):

*Possibly* the most elegant and simplest solution is the one in [this answer](//superuser.com/a/940439) mentioned by fixer1234 in [this comment](//superuser.com/questions/1350831/#comment2025219_1350831):

```dart
=MOD(B1-A1,1)
```

Note that it assumes that both values are time values only (or that the date part is to be truncated), i.e. each is less than 1, and that the duration is less than 24 hours.

**Explanation:**

This works because for a serial datetime value, a 1 corresponds to 24 hours, and a time-only value is a datetime value less than 1. Thus:

- If `B1 >= A1` then `MOD(B1-A1,1)`→`B1-A1` as expected
  or
- If `B1 < A1` then `MOD(B1-A1,1)` is equivalent to `1-(A1-B1)` (since `MOD(-n,m)=m-MOD(n,m)`) which gives the correct "complement" duration

---

An alternative solution (you judge if it's simpler/more elegant ;-) ) is:

```dart
=(B1<A1)+B1-A1
```

**Explanation:**

This works because `TRUE` values are implicitly coerced to a `1`, and `FALSE` values to a `0`, when used in arithmetic operations. Thus:

- If `B1 >= A1` then `(B1<A1)`→`0` and the formula becomes `B1-A1`
  or
- If `B1 < A1` then `(B1<A1)`→`1` and the formula is equivalent to `1-(A1-B1)`

Note that this formula will work correctly *even if both values are datetimes **and** are more than 24 hours apart!* This is *not* the case for the first formula, so this second formula is a more useful/general one.

Comment: I’m not sure what your last paragraph is saying.  If we assume that duration < 24 hours — i.e., that (start time) ≤ (end time) < (start time + 24 hours) — and you’re not worried about correctly handling the case where both cells have a true (full) datetime, then `=MOD(B1-A1, 1)` seems to work fairly well.  And ``=IF(AND(A2>=1,B2>=A2), B2-A2, IF(AND(A2>=0,A2<1,B2>=0,B2<1), MOD(B2-A2,1), "Error"))`` seems to handle all cases well.

Comment: @Scott I was just *waiting* for someone to pick up on that ;-)  I was specifically referring to [this comment](//superuser.com/q/1350831/#comment2025273_1350943) by Akina and the ensuing thread. After writing it, I realised that the paragraph is technically slightly inaccurate. What I needed to add was, "if there are no other assumptions made" and "always generate the correct difference". You are right in that if you simply wish to truncate a full datetime value, then the MOD formula will work. (Plus the error formula also handles the case by trapping it.) I'll delete it as it's OT/inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> just puts the current time into the cell without a datestamp, and as @Akina points out in his answer, it locks nothing.

`NOW()` adds a datestamp to the cell as well as the time.  To see that, click an **unformatted empty cell or any cell in `General` format** and type `=NOW()`.  At the time of typing this I get `21/08/2018 11:25`.

If you put `=NOW()` into cell `A1` and `=NOW()+TIME(23,0,0)` into cell `B1`, if you then put `=B1-A1` into cell `C1` and format the cell to `Time` you will get `23:00:00`.

If you are putting times in without datestamps, you will need to use an `IF()` formula to determine if the second time is lower than the first (time frame goes past midnight).  The following will work out the time difference between the time in cell `B1` and cell `A1` whether the end time is past midnight or not.  It will also work with or without datestamps as the datestamps are ignored.

`=IF(B1<A1,MOD(B1-A1,1),B1-A1)`

### Explanation of the formula

`=IF(B1<A1,...)`

is time in cell `B1` past midnight?  If so, the next part is executed

`MOD(B1-A1,1)`

The `MOD(number,divisor)` returns the remainder after a number is divided by a divisor.  Cell `B1` minus cell `A1` is a negative value as the time in cell `B1` is past midnight and excel doesn't like negative time values in most cases, hence it will give `#####` without the `MOD()`.  The `MOD()` sorts that out.

An alternative to the `MOD()` formula would be to use

`TIME(23,59,59)-TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))+TIME(0,0,1)+B1`

Which is `23:59:59 minus time in cell A1 plus 1 second plus time in cell B1`.

The last bit which is `,B1-A1)` is the last part of the `IF()` where if time in cell `B1` is **not** past midnight.

Comment: This formula may (it seems will - but it's sloth to check) give wrong result if one of source values is "fixed" (and do NOT contain date part, it is time only) whereas the other one is not (and contain both date and time parts).

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying @Akina.  I just checked and, actually, `=IF(B1<A1,MOD(B1-A1,1),B1-A1)` works whether there is a datestamp or not.

Comment: Insert current time (by pressing `Ctrl-Alt-;`) into A1 cell. Insert curent datetime (by formula `=NOW()`) into B1 cell. Check the result.

Comment: I did as you suggested, although it is `Ctrl + Shift + ;` into cell `A1`, and it works for me.

Comment: A1 contains the value looks like `00/01/1900 14:28` (while using full datetime value format) and B1 contains the value looks like `12/08/2018 14:28`, is it? And the result is NOT 43333?

Comment: If I reformat cell `A1` to `dd/mm/yy hh:mm` I have `00/01/1900 12:36` in `A1` and `21/08/2018 12:36` in `B2` and the result is  00:00:28 (28 seconds)

Comment: Let's look... `IF(B1<A1` => `IF '21/08/2018 12:36' < '00/01/1900 12:36'` => False. Agree? If so, the result is `B1-A1` => `'21/08/2018 12:36' - '00/01/1900 12:36'`. Agree? And now explain how the result can be `00:00:28 (28 seconds)`...

Comment: And why you say *and 21/08/2018 12:36 in **B2** and* whereas you use `B1` in your formula?

Comment: Come on, that's a typo and if you follow my instructions in my answer you get 28 seconds.  If you format cell C1 to `[mm]` you get 62399533 minutes

Comment: You shouldn't need an IF test.  MOD should handle the difference regardless of whether it passes midnight.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @Akina this is the only formula that worked for me... I tried several of the above-with positive vote counts mind you-and got the dreaded ###### or some negative number with several decimal points.  Accounted for times that span two days WITHOUT date stamps and all that mumbo jumbo...

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139175)

Answer (score -2):

> How do I calculate the duration if data in Column B include the timing that fall on the next day?

```
=1 + B1 - A1
```

formatted as a time will show the correct result. If B1 > A1, the resilt, of course, contain a non-zero date part, but it is not shown because of a cell format.

If you want to use this time value in some time calculations, use more complex formula

```
=B1-A1-INT(B1-A1)
```

PS.

> and lock with CTRL+SHIFT+;

This combination locks nothing. It fully replaces the cell content with current time value.

Comment: Well yeah it only change it to time value, but it does prevent the time to be change automatically since I am using a volatile formula =now().

Is there a way to lock a cell data?

Comment: @Saphiraz I don't understand you. When any source cell contains NOW() and its timepoint is not fixed the result in С (as I understand) doesn't matter. When both source cells are fixed by `Ctrl-Shift-;` the formula gives the result you need. **PS.** Look for `=B1-INT(B1)-A1+INT(A1)-INT(B1-A1)`...

Comment: please check the sample data.

Comment: *please check the sample data* What can I check on a screenshot? Add formatted (fixed-length) sample data (which can be easily copy-pasted to Excel sheet) into your question (specifying source range if need) with the reference result. For datetimes - type numbers and specify column(s) format.

Answer (score -2):

*To get difference in `Minutes` between two `24Hrs DateTime Stamps` you can use either of it :*

```
=Int((A2-A1)*24*60)
```

Or

```
=int((A2-A1)*1440)
```

Or

```
=ROUNDUP((A2-A1)*1440,2)
```

**Note,** Formula cell must have `General` Format.

Comment: After *lock with CTRL+SHIFT+;* there is no date-part in a value. If over-midnight the result will be negative.

Comment: I've recorded two value using `CTRL+SHIFT+;` are `2:03 PM` & `2:11 PM` & applied `=INT((M8-L8)*1440)&" Mnts"` got answer `8 Mnts`.

Comment: ,,Cont. or you may use `=ROUNDUP((M8-L8)*1440,2)&" Mnts"` also.

Comment: *got answer 8 Mnts* Swap source values - will the result be 1432?

Comment: If the time in cell `A2` is past midnight, the formulas in your answer do not work as @Akina points out

Comment: @ChrisRogers, thanks you raise the point let me check ,, since at my place is evening, let me reset the time to check it.

Comment: @ChrisRogers, No it's working properly I've `08:00 AM` & `12:30 AM` and this `=INT((A$2-A$1) * 1440)&" Mnts." `gives `5310 Mnts`. ☺

Comment: I do not understand how you get `5310 Mnts` when I get `480 Mnts` (8 hours).

Comment: @ChrisRogers, check the cell format should be 24 Hrs format

Comment: It is.  I put 08:00 into `A1` and 00:30 in `B1` and get `480 Mnts` in `C1` with the formula `=INT((A$2-A$1) * 1440)&" Mnts."`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82000/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-chris-rogers).

Comment: how do i upload spreadsheet here? does google sheet works for you both?

Comment: @Saphiraz, Yes attach the Sheet with Imgur or use other cloud application, I've edited it few times before.